# ADB over wireless - How do I get it working?

Tags: adb

It's extremely frustrating to see the wireless `adb` repeatedly fail, when the process must seem very straightforward. Here's how I got it working after an hour of screaming at my screen.

Answer (score 0):

## Note

`adb pair` must run before `adb connect`!! Without this, it will not work even if everything else is alright.

### Now the other things

1. Forgot the wifi network on phone and reconnect.
2. Use sudo
3. In dev settings, press and hold on the `Wireless ADB` to open the full menu.
4. Click on `Pair device with pairing code` - use that IP address (eg. say IP was 192.168.0.123:45678) with `sudo adb pair 192.168.0.123:45678`
5. DO NOT CLOSE THE POPUP WHICH SHOWED YOU THE PAIRING CODE, it will reset the pairing port.
6. `adb` will ask for the pairing code, enter that.
7. It will successfully pair, if not retry everything above
8. Then hit `sudo adb connect` and see the notification on your phone indicating good connection.